# Why am I seeing boxes in the outline overview in illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, cc-2014

[image]

I have downloaded this vector graphic from a freebie site and when i see the outline overview using "ctrl+y", i can see these boxes. Why is this happening and how to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

The boxes indicate raster images. If you get rid of them, you will most likely lose all fills in the artwork. Often this occurs when vector art uses transparency and then is flattened or simply saving to the EPS format can often cause artwork to be expanded and flattened in this manner.

Of course, you could remove them and then reset the fills as needed.

Remove them like you would remove anything - select it and hit the delete key.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Object - Expand the selected object.

Comment: Hi Miroslava, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit and tell why this answers the question? Thanks! If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I have to agree with Vincent can you elaborate on this answer.

Comment: Expanding will only result in *more* of these raster images. THey appear initially due to expanding fills for a flat file format, most often EPS.